# Display total reviews and ratings average of users own listing in codeignitor

Tags: php, mysql

I stuck in a problem that I want to show all the reviews of users own listing in a CodeIgniter project. There is two table in the database one is reviews and other is listings.

reviews table

[image]

listings table

[image]

common attribute is user_id and listed_by in both the tables. Now I want to get all the reviews of the listing which is created by `user_id(2)`. Is it possible?

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this requirement

Comment: I was trying to apply the joins but unable to fit...

Comment: Update your question with the query you have attempted

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya can you suggest some?

Comment: @Hitesh check the answer. The way I am understanding the problem is that you want to find all those reviews, which are on the listings done by user_id = 2 and the reviews are also written by user_id = 2 ?

Comment: No reviews can be written by anyone... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do a simple `JOIN` between the two tables based on listing id
- Select all reviews, based on the where condition, that is, `listed_by = 2`.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM reviews AS r 
JOIN listings AS l on l.id = r.listing_id 
WHERE l.listed_by = 2
```

Comment: the review can be written by anyone...

Comment: @Hitesh check the updated answer.